# Serial number generation algorithm for C# application

Tags: c#, php, hash, public-key-encryption, serial-number

I am  developing a shareware c# application which accepts a serial key generated in my website.

I am following  the following approach suggested by Joseph Spiros

> You bundle your public key with the application.
>   When the user buys the application, they supply their name and e-mail address.
>   The web site hashes the user's name and e-mail address, signs the hash with your private >key, and provides the result in Base64 to ease typing.
>   When the user enters the "code" into your application along with their name and e-mail >address, your application can verify that it was signed by your private key (which only >you/the web store has access to), and that it matches the name and e-mail provided by the >user.

My website runs on linux server so that the program generating the licence will be written in php. The software is developed using  c#. Please tell me whether the licence/hash generated and signed using a private key in php will be compatible with the public key in C#.

A pointer to an example would be helpful.

Comment: BTW, the language is "C#", not "CSHARP" or "C-SHARP".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [Shareware Starter Kit](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/danielfe/archive/2005/07/10/437293.aspx) for an example of licensing shareware on a Microsoft stack.